# Android: How to display text in certain milliseconds while media (mp3) is playing

Tags: android, arrays, handler, media-player

I'm trying to do a *karaoke-like application*. **I want to display a word or words when a certain milliseconds come. For example:**

1148 ms -> print "Nicholas "
1826 ms -> print "was "
2766 ms -> print "older "
...
*** ms -> display "*** "

**Here's my code:**

package com.example.hellomedia;

import java.io.IOException;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HelloMedia extends Activity {

```
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    final TextView tv = new TextView(this);

    tv.setText("Playing... ");
    setContentView(tv);

    final MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.nicholas);




    final String words[] = {
            "Nicholas ",// 0
            "was ", // 1
            "older ",// 2
            "than ",// 3
            "sin ",// 4
            "and ",// 5
            "his ",// 6
            "beard ",// 7
            "could ",// 8
            "go ",// 9
            "no ",// 10
            "whiter. "// 11
    };



    try {
        mPlayer.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mPlayer.start();

    mHandler.post(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){ 

            //tv.setText(" [ " + mPlayer.getCurrentPosition() + " ] ");
            if( mPlayer.getCurrentPosition() == 1148 ){//0
                tv.append(words[0]);
            }
            if( mPlayer.getCurrentPosition() == 1826 ){//1
                tv.append(words[1]);
            }
            if( mPlayer.getCurrentPosition() == 2766 ){//2
                tv.append(words[2]);
            }
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1);
        }    
    });


}
```

}

When I run this, no word(s) from the array is being printed.

I'm new to android dev. Many thanks in advance. :)

---

Thanks for all your responses @Matthew Willis, @MarvinLabs, and @Bill Mote. I came up exactly with what I needed. My code goes something like this:

```
package com.example.hellomedia;

import java.io.IOException;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class HelloMedia extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    final Handler mHandler = new Handler();
    final TextView tv = new TextView(this);

    tv.setText("Playing1... ");
    setContentView(tv);

    final MediaPlayer mPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.nicholas);

    try {
        mPlayer.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mPlayer.start();


    final String words[] = {
            "Nicholas ",// 0
            "was ", // 1
            "older ",// 2
            "than ",// 3
            "sin ",// 4
            "and ",// 5
            "his ",// 6
            "beard ",// 7
            "could ",// 8
            "go ",// 9
            "no ",// 10
            "whiter. "// 11
    };

    final long startEndTime[][]={
            {   //start time
                1148,// 0,0
                1826, // 0,1
                2766,// 0,2
                3079,// 0,3
                3549,// 0,4
                4540,// 0,5
                4697,// 0,6
                4801,// 0,7
                5114,// 0,8
                5323,// 0,9
                5532,// 0,10
                5845// 0,11
            },
            {   //end time
                1357,// 1,0
                2192, // 1,1
                3027,// 1,2
                3183,// 1,3
                3966,// 1,4
                4645,// 1,5
                4749,// 1,6
                4958,// 1,7
                5219,// 1,8
                5427,// 1,9
                5740,// 1,10
                6210// 1,11
            }

        };

    mHandler.post(new Runnable(){

        public void run(){ 
            final long currentPos = mPlayer.getCurrentPosition();

            int x = 0;

            while( x < 12){
                if( currentPos > startEndTime[0][x] && currentPos < startEndTime[1][x] ){//0
                    tv.append(words[x]);
                    words[x]="";
                }
                x++;
            }

            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 1);
        }    
    });


}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not guaranted that your message handler will be called exactly each millisecond. You must give it some slack:

```
 mHandler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage(Message msg){     
            final long currentPos = mPlayer.getCurrentPosition();

            if (currentPos > 1100 && currentPos < 1300) {
                tv.append(words[0]);
            } else if (currentPos > 1300 && currentPos < 1400) {
                tv.append(words[1]);
            } 

            mHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 1);
        }
    };


mHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
```

Comment: This will lead to multiple words displayed if you don't keep track of whether or not you displayed each word.

Comment: @Matthew I agree, just using what the OP posted to show where the mistake was. He will quickly notice that the screen gets filled with words :)

Answer (score 2):

What about using an inequality to measure the milliseconds:

```
if (mPlayer.getCurrentPosition() > 1148) {
    ...
```

It's very unlikely that your function will be called when the playback position is exactly 1148.

Then you will need to keep track of the words that you have already displayed so that you don't display them twice.

Comment: I also thought that was the problem... do you think the app that i'm trying to do is impossible?

Comment: No, just use an inequality and keep track of how many words you've displayed so far. Your app seems very possible, and you're almost there.

Comment: Agree that Matthew has you on the right path.  Matthew, is an array of "pairs" possible?  Saw .pair the other day and haven't done anything with it.  Would that be an avenue to keep a word and a position (in ms) together?

Comment: @Bill, yes, that seems reasonable. Then you could just pop them off the front of a queue as you go along.

Comment: @Matthew Willis / @Bill Mote : How will I be able to keep track of how many words I've displayed so far? I have these condition: if( currentPos > 1148 && currentPos < 1357 ){ tv.append(words[0]); } ...... - thanks to @MarvinLabs. But it displays: Nicholas Nicholas Nicholas Nicholas Nicholas was was was was older older older older older

Comment: Think about storing the words together with their times in a queue. In your function, check to see if the play time is greater than the time for the word at the front of the queue. If it is, display the word and then pop the word off the queue.